# python alternative for awk?

Tags: python, awk, bioinformatics

I have two fasta files, and I want to search for sequence IDs and assign only the sequence corresponding to the ID to a string in Python.

I currently have:

```
import os
#use awk on the command line to search reference file and cut the reference sequence
os.system("awk '/LOC_OS05G45410.1/{getline;print}' Ref_seqs.fasta > sangerRef") 

#use awk on the command line to cut the aligned sequence
os.system("awk '/seq1/{getline;print}' Sanger_seq_1.fasta > sangerAlign")

Ref_seq = open('sangerRef', 'r').read()
Sanger_seq = open('sangerAlign', 'r').read()
```

When I print these variables, everything looks fine:

```
TGGTGAGGCTTTTGACAGGGTTGAGCTGAGCCTGGTCTCCCTGGAGAAACTCTTCCAGAGAGCAAATGATGCTTGCACAGCTGCTGAAGAAATGTACTCCCATGGTCATGGTGGTACTGAACCCAG

CTGCTGCCCAAGTACTTCAAGCACAACAACTTCTCCAGCTTCATCAGGCAGCTCAACGCCTACGGTTTCCGAAAAATCGATCCTGAGAGATGGGAGTTCGCAAACGAGGATTTCATAAGAGGGCACACGCACCTT
```

However, when I try to read these variables into another function, it doesn't work:

```
from Bio import pairwise2
from Bio.Align import substitution_matrices

#load sequences
s1=Ref_seq
s2=Sanger_seq
matrix = substitution_matrices.load("NUC.4.4")
gap_open = -10
gap_extend = -0.5

align = pairwise2.align.globalds(s1, s2, matrix, gap_open, gap_extend)

align
```

I'm thinking it might be better to replace the awk command with a Python command?

Comment: What, exactly, does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: the function starts running and never stops

Comment: test it by assigning the known string to a python variable and then pass that in. Comment out the `awk` lines. It seems more likely that the function you are calling has a problem, but this will be a quick way to determine if awk is at fault, but yes, `python` can easily do the string processing for you, so it makes sense to do some research on how to acheive that. Good luck.

Comment: I wonder if https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you haven't parsed the sequences. I don't know if I am using the word 'Parse' right, though.

I think this should work

```py
from Bio import SeqIO

s1 = SeqIO.read('filepath/filename.fasta','fasta')
s2 = SeqIO.read('filepath/file.fasta','fasta')

matrix = substitution_matrices.load("NUC.4.4")

gap_open = -10
gap_extend = -0.5

align = pairwise2.align.globalds(s1.seq, s2.seq, matrix, gap_open, gap_extend)
align
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you are assuming that each FASTA file contains just a single sequence. The Awk script looks for one specific sequence in a FASTA file which presumably contains more than one sequence.

Comment: if it contains multiple lines or sequences you can set the alignment mode to 'local' .

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that `read()` returns all the lines with a newline at the end of each.

But indeed, your Awk commands should be trivial to replace with native Python.

```py
def getseq(filename, search):
    with open(filename) as reffile:
        for line in reffile:
            if search in line:
                return seqfile.__next__().rstrip('\n')

s1 = getseq("Ref_seqs.fasta", "LOC_OS05G45410.1")
s2 = getseq("Sanger_seq_1.fasta", "seq1")
```

Probably BioPython already contains a better function for doing this. In particular, your Awk script (and hence this blind reimplementation) assumes that each sequence only occupies one line in the file.